# unity 5 il2cpp support for ios simulator

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, il2cpp

Is unity5's IL2CPP support IOS simulator build now? I managed to build a unity exported project in xcode but when it run in simulator mode it crashed with the message dyld: Symbol not found: _CloseZStream.

Comment: Do you use any plugins for native iOS functionality? I think the problem might be in plugins.

Comment: In general, the iOS Simulator does work with IL2CPP projects. This specific case might be a problem related to the use the DeflateStream in managed code though. Does your code use that?